# Small custom build of SQLite3

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

We are using sqlite3 in an application and we really need a super small build of sqlite3 by removing unnecessary functions. We are already using -Os flag.

Our application only uses a single table with couple of indexes and simple select, update, insert, delete queries. All the columns are either integer, text or blob.

I tried to generate custom build of sqlite3.c from canonical source by using various SQLITE_OMIT_* flags below but seems to have only marginal impact on the binary size.

Any suggestions on other OMIT options. Also if any of the OMIT options has any side effects for the limited use I mentioned above.

```
-DSQLITE_OMIT_ALTERTABLE 
-DSQLITE_OMIT_ANALYZE 
-DSQLITE_OMIT_ATTACH 
-DSQLITE_OMIT_AUTHORIZATION 
-DSQLITE_OMIT_BUILTIN_TEST 
-DSQLITE_OMIT_CAST 
-DSQLITE_OMIT_CHECK 
-DSQLITE_OMIT_COMPILEOPTION_DIAGS 
-DSQLITE_OMIT_COMPLETE 
-DSQLITE_OMIT_COMPOUND_SELECT 
-DSQLITE_OMIT_CTE 
-DSQLITE_OMIT_DATETIME_FUNCS 
-DSQLITE_OMIT_DECLTYPE 
-DSQLITE_OMIT_DEPRECATED 
-DSQLITE_OMIT_EXPLAIN 
-DSQLITE_OMIT_FLAG_PRAGMAS 
-DSQLITE_OMIT_FLOATING_POINT 
-DSQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY
-DSQLITE_OMIT_UTF16
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use all the `SQLITE_OMIT_xxx` options because you did not mention using any of those features.

Don't use `SQLITE_OMIT_WSD`, which does not actually remove code and would make the library bigger.

Using `SQLITE_OMIT_AUTOINIT` would not make sense.

If you forgot to mention that the data is stored on disk, you should avoid `SQLITE_OMIT_DISKIO`.

Comment: the size reduction is extremely negligible even after omitting most features - around 10-15k, not worth removing IMO.